# NoMethodError - undefined method `present?' for nil:NilClass:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Disclaimer - I'm a Java developer with zero Ruby experience.

I'm trying to update the Ruby version of a legacy company application so that I can leverage a better telemetry client library which is incompatible with our old Ruby version.  After updating our Gemfile to remove some restrictions and bumping the version of Ruby from 2.3.1 to 2.7.3 and Bundler from 1.7.13 to 2.2.17.  After this our site is returning errors about not recognizing the formerly recognized 'blank?' and 'present?' methods.  My understanding is that these are part of Rails extensions, not native Ruby but if we don't have that framework in the mix here how would those have worked previously?

I'm not even really sure what information Ruby people want in these situations but I've not modified any source code so the Gemfile.lock files seem appropriate.  Sorry for my level of ignorance here, been flailing for a day or so and Google hasn't gotten me over the hump.  Hoping this is an easy one for someone in the Ruby community.

Old Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activesupport (4.2.5)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    backports (3.16.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    colorize (0.7.7)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    ethon (0.9.1)
      ffi (>= 1.3.0)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    hashie (3.4.3)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.4)
    listen (3.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    macaddr (1.7.1)
      systemu (~> 2.6.2)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    metaclass (0.0.4)
    mime-types (2.99)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.2.3)
    mocha (1.1.0)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.14.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mustermann (1.1.1)
      ruby2_keywords (~> 0.0.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    omniauth (1.3.1)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    omniauth-saml (1.4.1)
      omniauth (~> 1.1)
      ruby-saml (~> 1.0.0)
    pg (0.18.4)
    pony (1.11)
      mail (>= 2.0)
    power_assert (0.2.6)
    puma (2.15.3)
    rack (2.1.0)
    rack-mobile-detect (0.4.0)
      rack
    rack-protection (2.0.8.1)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    redis (3.2.2)
    rerun (0.11.0)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    ruby-saml (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.10)
      uuid (~> 2.3)
    ruby-saml-idp (0.3.2)
      uuid
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.2)
    sequel (4.29.0)
    sequel_pg (1.6.13)
      pg (>= 0.8.0)
      sequel (>= 3.39.0)
    shoulda (3.5.0)
      shoulda-context (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
      shoulda-matchers (>= 1.4.1, < 3.0)
    shoulda-context (1.2.1)
    shoulda-matchers (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sinatra (2.0.8.1)
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.0.8.1)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    sinatra-contrib (2.0.8.1)
      backports (>= 2.8.2)
      multi_json
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.0.8.1)
      sinatra (= 2.0.8.1)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    systemu (2.6.5)
    test-unit (3.1.5)
      power_assert
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    typhoeus (1.1.0)
      ethon (>= 0.9.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uuid (2.3.8)
      macaddr (~> 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt
  colorize
  erubis
  faraday
  jwt
  minitest (~> 5.2.0)
  mocha
  omniauth-saml
  pg
  pony
  puma (= 2.15.3)
  rack (= 2.1.0)
  rack-mobile-detect
  rack-test
  rake
  redis
  rerun
  ruby-saml
  ruby-saml-idp
  sequel
  sequel_pg
  shoulda
  sinatra (= 2.0.8.1)
  sinatra-contrib (= 2.0.8.1)
  test-unit
  typhoeus

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

New Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activesupport (6.1.3.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    colorize (0.8.1)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.8)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    ethon (0.14.0)
      ffi (>= 1.15.0)
    faraday (1.4.1)
      faraday-excon (~> 1.1)
      faraday-net_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-net_http_persistent (~> 1.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)
    faraday-excon (1.1.0)
    faraday-net_http (1.0.1)
    faraday-net_http_persistent (1.1.0)
    ffi (1.15.0)
    hashie (4.1.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jwt (2.2.3)
    listen (3.5.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mini_mime (1.1.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.5.1)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    mocha (1.12.0)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    mustermann (1.1.1)
      ruby2_keywords (~> 0.0.1)
    newrelic_rpm (7.0.0)
    nio4r (2.5.7)
    nokogiri (1.11.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    omniauth (2.0.4)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
      rack-protection
    omniauth-saml (2.0.0)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
      ruby-saml (~> 1.9)
    pg (1.2.3)
    pony (1.13.1)
      mail (>= 2.0)
    power_assert (2.0.0)
    puma (5.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mobile-detect (0.4.0)
      rack
    rack-protection (2.1.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rake (13.0.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.2.5)
    rerun (0.13.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    ruby-saml (1.12.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.10.5)
      rexml
    ruby-saml-idp (0.3.5)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.4)
    sequel (5.44.0)
    sequel_pg (1.14.0)
      pg (>= 0.18.0, != 1.2.0)
      sequel (>= 4.38.0)
    shoulda (4.0.0)
      shoulda-context (~> 2.0)
      shoulda-matchers (~> 4.0)
    shoulda-context (2.0.0)
    shoulda-matchers (4.5.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    sinatra (2.1.0)
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 2.2)
      rack-protection (= 2.1.0)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    sinatra-contrib (2.1.0)
      multi_json
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.1.0)
      sinatra (= 2.1.0)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    test-unit (3.4.1)
      power_assert
    tilt (2.0.10)
    typhoeus (1.4.0)
      ethon (>= 0.9.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt
  colorize
  erubis
  faraday
  jwt
  minitest
  mocha
  newrelic_rpm
  omniauth-saml
  pg
  pony
  puma
  rack
  rack-mobile-detect
  rack-test
  rake
  redis
  rerun
  ruby-saml
  ruby-saml-idp
  sequel
  sequel_pg
  shoulda
  sinatra
  sinatra-contrib
  test-unit
  typhoeus

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Comment: Updating Rails / ActiveSupport from 4.2.5 to 6.1.3.2 seems to be the major issue. There’s an [Upgrading Ruby on Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) guide which covers the upgrade process, including `rake rails:update`.

Answer (score 4):

Well good for me, dug down one other thread with several links and eventually found some information that, at some point, the Rails core extensions were modularized. Now these can require explicit importing (require keyword, sorry if my Ruby lingo is off) thus adding

```
require "active_support"
require "active_support/core_ext/object"
```

Seems to have fixed my issue.  Of course if anyone who knows this stuff well looks at this post and sees that I'm doing something really boneheaded (more than likely) please correct me and show me the light.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: This simple works for me. Thanks man.